# Semantic dichotomy could validate denying antecedent?

Tags: fallacies, semantics

We imagine a controversial political situation.

If the politician resigns from office (A), then they are doing the right thing (B)."
The politician does not resign from office (-A), therefore they are doing the "wrong" thing ("-B"?)."

On the face of it, this looks like denying the antecedent, and therefore invalid. But I'm troubled by the semantics. Wrong is the antonym of right, so one might assume that "not right" equals "wrong". But that is predicated on "right" and "wrong" being a discrete dichotomy.

What does logical semantics have to say about this?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you apply logic, you have to follow logic rules: no ambiguities at all. Thus, if right=not wrong, then the above is a logical (invalid) argument. Is right means something different, then it is only a statement whatever.

Comment: Why does this have to be an inference? Both can be true (insofar as one can make sense of words as vague as "right" and "wrong" in the context) for independent reasons. Or both validly follow from "the right thing to do (in such and such situation) is to resign" (equivalence). Vagueness of equating "not right" to "wrong" is a separate issue.